# Breakpoints in d8 debugger. Do they exist?

Tags: javascript, v8

I googled info about v8 and its d8 debugger api and flags but didn't find any information about way to set breakpoints or step through code. Did I miss something?

So is there a way to set a breakpoint at a particular line and column? If so then how it should be done.

Update: `debugger;` statement is not what I am looking for. I am looking for breakpoints that can be set at particular line/column

Update: I speak about d8 (c++ shell program) not about dev tools that are build on top of it

Comment: Maybe with the `debugger;` statement?

Comment: Maybe insert the debugger statement programmatically then? Abd i dont think that this is actually useful.

Comment: you can click on the line number (in the source tab of the dev tools) to add a breakpoint

Comment: According to https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Debugging-over-the-V8-Inspector-API#connecting-to-inspector, there is a rudimental debugging API in d8. As documentation it links to the involved classes, though…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V8 developer here. The `d8` shell does not contain a debugger.

When you run it with `--enable-inspector`, it exposes access to the "InspectorProtocol" API, which makes it possible to run tests for inspector/debugger functionality in d8. See the link Bergi provided, or the tests in V8's repository, for details and examples. This is not intended for interactive usage though. (Doing so would be *possible*, strictly speaking, but extremely inconvenient.)

If you want to debug JavaScript, Chrome's DevTools are the recommended approach.

Comment: Thk for a detailed response. My goal is to embed JS debugger in my application to allow step by step JS execution (with ability to see stacks, closures ect.). So I was exploring v8 and d8 with intent to modify its source for this needs. As for V8 developer is it possible for you to say how much work (approximately) task of making  API for basic debugger functions (stepping through code, setting breakpoints, seeing stacks) on top of V8 source will require (and is V8 the best candidate for such modifications).

Comment: You don't need to modify V8 at all for that. You simply need to build your UI, and can use the InspectorProtocol to talk to V8. Just like Chrome's DevTools. I don't know how much work that would be (and that obviously also depends a lot on what exactly you want to build).

Comment: Ok, but where can we find e description of what the embedder of V8 has to do in order to allow CDT to connect and debug a running script? Is there an example/sample in v8 sources which can be debugged via CDT?